# fibration of complex projective space over quaternion projective space

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fibration, hopf-fibration

From the fibration $$Sp(1)=S^3\to S^{4n+3}\to \mathbb{H}P^n,$$ can we quotient the action of $U(1)=S^1$ and obtain a well-defined fibration
$$
S^2\to \mathbb{C}P^{2n+2}\to\mathbb{H}P^n?$$

Consequently, can we obtain a fibration of limit
$$
S^2\to \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}\to\mathbb{H}P^\infty?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely analogously to my answer of [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043185/fibration-of-real-projective-space-over-complex-projective-space) by taking $G=Sp(1)=S^3, H=U(1)=S^1$.

One concludes that 
$$Sp(1)\rightarrow ESp(1)=S^{\infty}\rightarrow BSp(1)=\mathbb{H}P^{\infty}$$ is a model for the universal principal $Sp(1)$-bundle and the bundle you mention is just $$Sp(1)/U(1)=S^2\rightarrow BU(1)=\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}\rightarrow BSp(1)=\mathbb{H}P^{\infty}.$$

Comment: yes. thank you so much!